# Does anyone offer a for-pay packaging service to generate appropriate packages and put them in a ppa?

Tags: ppa, packaging

We have an application designed to work within ubuntu that has a nest of twisty dependencies, all alike.

We've reached the point where we have to create a package for it, and we're finding our ubuntu packaging skills sadly not up to the task.

Is there a service that, for a fee, packages, prepares, performs necessary backports, and puts them on a PPA?

Comment: I understand if this is off topic. I'm mainly looking for search-terms and venues, rather than a specific recommendation of "this guy."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debian maintains [a list of consultants](http://www.debian.org/consultants/) who provide paid Debian support. Presumably, some of them will have the relevant experience.

Freexian, run by Raphaël Hertzog (a respected Debian Developer), provides a variety of Debian related services [including packaging](http://www.freexian.com/en/services/debian-packaging.html).

There is also a [debian-jobs mailing list](http://lists.debian.org/debian-jobs/) where people sometime solicit this type of work.